# MVC API Routing Parameters

Tags: string, model-view-controller, parameters, routes, http-status-code-404

I have a MVC Web API on the .NET Core 2.2

When I use the URL such as: 
https://localhost:44374/HorseRacingApi/prices/GetPricesForRace/2019-07-11T00:00:00/14/1

It works fine, but when I use the URL like a query string:
https://localhost:44374/HorseRacingApi/prices/GetPricesForRace?meetingDate=2019-07-11T00:00:00&courseId=14&raceNumber=1

I get a 404 error, is there a way to fix this?

Here is the following controller and route setup:

```
[Route("HorseRacingApi/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class PricesController : Controller
{
    public IPriceService _priceService;

    public PricesController(IPriceService priceService)
    {
        _priceService = priceService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
 [Route("GetPricesForRace/{meetingDate}/{courseId}/{raceNumber}/{ShowAll?}")]
    public IActionResult GetPricesForRace(DateTime meetingDate, int courseId, int raceNumber, bool? ShowAll = false)
    {
         return Ok(_priceService.GetPricesForRace(meetingDate, courseId, raceNumber));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using

```
 [Route("GetPricesForRace")]
```

instead of

```
[Route("GetPricesForRace/{meetingDate}/{courseId}/{raceNumber}/{ShowAll?}")]
```

I can now use like a query string.